# Remote debugging inQT

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using Qt creator 2.6.1 based on 5.0.0. 
Target Which i am using DM3730 (Arm Processor).
I copied  gdbserver on target from codesourcery ,and run gdbserver :22 Qtexe on target.
From Host ,I have set Codesourcery GCC and GDB in Build and Run tab. I have added one new device for remote debug.
If i tried to Attach remote debug server , 
 Initially 
   This seems not be a debug build
After that ,
  Connecting to remote server failed tcp:22 conection refused error is coming. How to rectify this?
 And i want to build the Qt source in debug mode.i assume my Qt source was build in release Mode

Answer (score 0):

Port 22 is reserved for SSH, and ports < 1024 are reserved for several standard/system services altogether. I suggest you use a port number in the higher four-digit or the five-digit range; e. g. :2345. Make sure it doesn't collide with a custom service you're running on your target.